# Could not write JSON: (was java.lang.NullPointerException); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, pagination

In my recent project I have a requirement to send paginated list. I did pagination in my earlier project. Then I didn't face any error. But now I can't do pagination in my recent project. I don't know what's going wrong. I am providing my code step by step.

This is my controller class that return a custom page class

```
@GetMapping(value = "")
public CustomerResponsePage getCustomerList(@RequestParam Long agentId,
                                            @RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "0") Integer page) {
    if (agentId == null)
        throw new NullValueException("Null value received for agentId");
    return customerService.getCustomersOfAgent(agentId, page);
}
```

My service method is

```
 @Override
    public CustomerResponsePage getCustomersOfAgent(Long agentId, Integer page) {
        User agent = userService.read(agentId);
        if (agent == null)
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Agent with this id is not found");
        if (agent.getReferenceNo() == null)
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("No reference found for this agent");
        Page<User> customers = userRepository.findByReferenceNo(agent.getReferenceNo(),
                new PageRequest(page, PageAttr.PAGE_SIZE));
        List<UserDTO> dtoList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (User user : customers) {
            dtoList.add(customerMapper.customerResponseMapper(user));
        }
        System.out.println("Page is " + customers.getContent());
        System.out.println("List is " + dtoList);
        return new CustomerResponsePage(dtoList, customers);
    }
```

My custom page class is

```
public class CustomerResponsePage implements Page {


    private List<UserDTO> content;
    private Pageable pageable;
    private boolean last;
    private Integer totalPages;
    private Long totalElements;
    private Integer size;
    private Integer number;
    private Integer numberOfElements;
    private boolean first;
    private Sort sort;

    public CustomerResponsePage(List<UserDTO> content, Page page) {
        this.content = content;
        this.pageable = page.getPageable();
        this.last = page.isLast();
        this.totalPages = page.getTotalPages();
        this.totalElements = page.getTotalElements();
        this.size = page.getSize();
        this.number = page.getNumber();
        this.numberOfElements = page.getNumberOfElements();
        this.first = page.isFirst();
        this.sort = page.getSort();

        System.out.println("content is " + content.toString());
        System.out.println("Page value is " + page.getTotalElements());
        System.out.println("Content is " + page.getContent());
    }

    public void setContent(List<UserDTO> content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Override
    public Pageable getPageable() {
        return pageable;
    }

    @Override
    public int getTotalPages() {
        return this.totalPages;
    }

    @Override
    public long getTotalElements() {
        return this.totalElements;
    }

    @Override
    public Page map(Function function) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        return this.size;
    }

    @Override
    public int getNumberOfElements() {
        return this.numberOfElements;
    }

    @Override
    public List getContent() {
        return this.content;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasContent() {
        return this.content.size() > 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Sort getSort() {
        return this.sort;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFirst() {
        return this.first;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLast() {
        return this.last;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return !this.isLast();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPrevious() {
        return !this.isFirst();
    }

    @Override
    public Pageable nextPageable() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Pageable previousPageable() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator iterator() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I hit postman I get error like 
[image]

And in my console I got error like

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: (was java.lang.NullPointerException); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: com.sweetitech.capitalexpress.pageable.CustomerResponsePage["empty"])]
```

Note that inside `CustomerResponsePage` print method is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stack trace refers to a field in `CustomerResponsePage` named `empty`. The problem might be related to the serialization of that field or the result of its getter method.

If you don't need the field in your JSON output, you can use `@JsonIgnore` to skip it.

[edit]

In your snippet, a `CustomerResponsePage` is manually instantiated using `new CustomerResponsePage(dtoList, customers)`. By instantiating manually, Spring will not be able to handle pagination the way it normally would.

I would use the `map` function provided by `Page` instead of manually iterating through the `User` objects to create objects. Then you won't need the `CustomerResponsePage` as a wrapper for the objects and can return a `Page<UserDto>` instead.

```
Page<User> customers = userRepository.findByReferenceNo(agent.getReferenceNo(),
            new PageRequest(page, PageAttr.PAGE_SIZE));

Page<UserDto> userDtos = customers.map(c -> customerMapper.customerResponseMapper(c));

return userDtos;
```

Comment: In my domain class I added `@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)` on the top of class to exclude null field. So I am not getting any null field when I an retrieving database object.

Comment: If a method's _processed_ return value is null, Jackson will ignore not add it to the serialized response. Does `CustomerResponsePage` have a field named `empty` or a method named `isEmpty`, `empty`, and/or `getEmpty`? If so, verify whether a nullpointer exception occurs while the method processes.

Comment: No I have no field/method with name `empty` or `isEmpty` in `CustomerResponsePage`. I have already posted `CustomerResponsePage`. Please check.

Comment: `CustomerResponsePage` implements `Page`. The attribute might be on the interface your class implements. If you're using `org.springframework.data.domain.Page`, the method `isEmpty` is present, as the interface `Page` extends [Streamable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/util/Streamable.html). 

In your snippet, a `CustomerResponsePage` is manually instantiated using `new CustomerResponsePage(dtoList, customers)`. By instantiating manually, Spring might not be able to instantiate the fields the way it normally would.

Comment: What should I do now ? Any best approach ?

Comment: I've changed my original post and added an example, I couldn't get to format some demo code in this comment.

Comment: Ok, I will let you know after trying this.